# Custom ArrayAdapter without TextViews

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on an app with a `ListView` and I've created a custom `ArrayAdapter`. After overriding the `getView()` method and giving it a test run I've run into an exception claiming that I need to pass through the adapter's constructor the ID of a TextView.

Lucky me I have a TextView in my `ListView's` row `XML` design so it wasn't a problem.

But what if I didn't have one? How do I create an Adapter for a `ListView` with item's that don't include a `TextView`?

Comment: Your question is almost unclear ... please put your codes too

Comment: please put your code here

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter defaults to placing a String in a TextView.
For a more customizable adapter try this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html